# Meteor's Email is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, meteor

After adding Meteor's email package and restarting the server (for good measure), I do this:

```
Template.messaging.events({
  'click #send-message' : function () {
    Email.send({
      from: 'test@gmail.com',
      to:   'test2@gmail.com',
      html: 'heyo buddy.'
    });
  }
});
```

When I fire the event, the console spits out:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Email is not defined
```

The docs say that even unconfigured, Email.send() should output to standard output. I get the same problem when deployed to meteor.com, which should be automatically set up with Mailgun.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#email), Email is a server-side only package. You are trying to invoke it client-side within a Template callback. I suggest you move your above calls into a server-side method via Meteor.methods, and then invoke it client-side via Meteor.call

Comment: Thanks! The docs could have been much clearer with an example, though. I submitted a pull-request; hopefully no one else falls into this trap.