# Meteor Email not defined, but is running from Meteor.methods

Tags: meteor

I have the following Meteor method set up:

```
// Defined in collections/collections.js
Meteor.methods({
    email: function(options) {
        this.unblock();
        Email.send(options);
    }
});
```

which I call like this:

```
// Defined in client/main.js
Meteor.call('email', {
    to: 'yeahright@noneya.com', from: 'yeahright@noneya.com',
    text: 'testing testing'
});
```

I get two errors, one in the browser console:

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'email' 
ReferenceError {stack: "ReferenceError: Email is not defined↵    at Meteor…js?acc2397bd1f7321a583a30e0d4628ec4f9fded4b:369:3", message: "Email is not defined"}
 ReferenceError: Email is not defined
(etc....)
```

the other in my server shell running `meteor`:

```
Exception while invoking method 'email' ReferenceError: Email is not defined
(etc....)
```

What's going on? I feel like I've followed the [documentation's instructions](http://docs.meteor.com/#email_send) exactly, and I'm not doing anything similarly wrong as in questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785312/meteors-email-is-undefined) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814537/meteorjs-am-i-using-email-send-correctly).

Comment: When you run the meteor server, have you set the MAIL_URL environment variable for your smtp service?

Comment: Also, try putting that first block `Meteor.methods` in /server **only**

Comment: @Paul, I haven't set that variable, and I just realized I don't even *have* an smtp service. ha I guess I assumed the Meteor guys took care of all that with the package. Yikes.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814537/meteorjs-am-i-using-email-send-correctly?lq=1 with solution https://github.com/airlok/meteor/commit/4624138692dd1f2e309100d21f2dce2fa6060643

Comment: Not sure if it is set up in dev to use local mailers or not... but it should work with mailgun or mandrill, which are free for limited use. These are outsourced smtp servers that you sign up to use....

Comment: Gut feeling is that the code posted is defining and running `email()` on the client, which then tries to run `Email.send()` on the client.  That can be fixed by putting the the first block in /server. Need to leave... good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103081/paul) suggested, it looks like the error is that you are trying to call `Email.send()` from the client.

`Email.send()` can only be called on the server. To solve the issue try moving the method definition to the server.

[Email.send()](http://docs.meteor.com/#email_send)

Answer (score 6):

Did you add the email package?

```
meteor add email
```

Comment: I also needed to do that! I feel stupid now... I always clicked on the `Email.send` link in the documentation, so I never saw the heading above it about how exactly to wire it up ha

Comment: I assumed that because the accounts package had sent email in the past, that the Email functions would also work out of the box. I was wrong. Thanks for this.