# Meteor Email not defined, but is running from Meteor.methods in Server Directory

Tags: email, meteor, methods

I have the following Meteor method set up inside my server directory:

```
// Defined in collections/collections.js
Meteor.methods({
    sendEmail: function(options) {
        this.unblock();
        Email.send(options);
    }
});
```

which I call like this:

```
// Defined in client/main.js
Meteor.call('sendEmail', {
    to: 'yeahright@noneya.com', from: 'yeahright@noneya.com',
    text: 'testing testing'
});
```

I get one error in server shell running Meteor:

> ```
> Exception while invoking method 'sendEmail' { stack: 'ReferenceError: Email is not defined\n    at [object
> ```
>
> Object].Meteor.methods.sendEmail
>   (app/server/methods/reservations.js:82:4)\n    at [object
>   Object].methodMap.(anonymous function)
>   (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/lib/hijack/wrap_session.js:164:1)\n    at
>   maybeAuditArgumentChecks
>   (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1711:12)\n    at
>   packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:711:19\n    at [object
>   Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)\n
>   at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:709:40\n    at [object
>   Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)\n
>   at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:707:46\n    at tryCallTwo
>   (/Users/sltwtr/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.7.3.1y6b71x++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)\n
>   at doResolve
>   (/Users/sltwtr/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.7.3.1y6b71x++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)',I20160721-11:50:31.471(-7)?
>   source: 'method' }

I've added the email package using

> meteor add email

What's going on?  Questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785312/meteors-email-is-undefined) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108924/meteor-email-not-defined-but-is-running-from-meteor-methods).

Comment: Did you import? `import { Email } from 'meteor/email'`

Comment: No, I didn't.  Did that start in version 1.2?  I don't have that anywhere in my code and it all seems to run okay.

Comment: It looks like you have an answer below, which seems correct, but to answer your comment, no, it was not added in 1.2.  You didn't specify which version of meteor you were using, so I assumed you were using 1.3 (latest), which support ES6 and it's new module loading.  In this case, you need to import stuff to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Email can only be sent from the server. Meteor.methods() is being called from the server and the client

Try the following:

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function(options) {
    if(Meteor.isServer){
      this.unblock();
      Email.send(options);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If the code is placed in the server directory,  Meteor.isServer is implied.

Comment: In theory - you are correct. I would still try what I posted though.